# psql cannot connect without -h flag

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am running `psql` from a Debian 8.7 terminal but cannot figure out why it needs the `-h` flag to execute. For example, if i run `psql -U postgres` on the terminal, I get the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

However, when I add the host flag, I am able to connect:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost

psql (9.4.10, server 9.6.2)
WARNING: psql major version 9.4, server major version 9.6.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

What is the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the client and the server have a different idea about the directory where UNIX sockets should be created.

While connected to the database, run

```
SHOW unix_socket_directories;
```

That will tell you in which directory (or directories) the UNIX socket can be found.

You can use the directory name with the `-h` option or set the environment variable `PGHOST` to it for a local connection.

For example, if the result you get is `/tmp` (the factory default), you can use

```
psql -h /tmp -U postgres
```

Comment: Setting the environment variable PGHOST solved the problem! Thank you!